# Select doesn't update model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I'm having on one page 2 select elements like this:

```
  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="country">Land</label>
   <select id="country" required class="form-control" ng-model="localCountriesObjectNL" ng-options="item as item.getName() for item in countries"></select>
 </div>
```

and:

```
  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="country">Country</label>
   <select id="country" required class="form-control" ng-model="localCountriesObjectEN" ng-options="item as item.getName() for item in engCountries"></select>
 </div>
```

in my code I have 2 scope variables like this:

```
$scope.localCountriesObjectNL;
$scope.localCountriesObjectEN;
```

When I change the language in de select with the NL object it works fine the model updates. The second one doesn't update the model. It always stays the same even when I click on another item in the select list.

Anyone an idea?

EDIT:

I just noticed that now the first doesn't update. So the problem occurs when I added the second html select on the page.

Comment: Post a plunker with the problem

Comment: BTW, your two selects have the same id. This is wrong.

Comment: The post that said you need to create an object and then a property in it. That solved the problem. If the one who posted this post it again I will give him the credit.